# React Native run IOS build failure

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, build-error

I'm new to developing react native apps for iOS. I created a project using react-native init. I have managed to install all the requirements mentioned on that page. However, I ran into an issue while installing cocoa pods, but I installed it with home-brew. But now, I run into this build issue.

I have attached the issue which showed up in the terminal as well as the screenshot of the build error on Xcode. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**terminal build fail code**

```
The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/ahyanawaz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Store-bekhqxqflgsqtyheijdxkrbwrksk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Core.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTDatePickerManager.o /Users/ahyanawaz/Desktop/Store/node_modules/react-native/React/Views/RCTDatePickerManager.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

**Xcode build time error**
[img01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQe3f.png)
[img02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhR3U.png)

Comment: Are You Using m1 Mac?

Comment: No I'm using a hackintosh. Xcode version is 10.1

Comment: 1. Make sure every package which you have installed is linked properly.
2. Find if you imported a package in a file and now you don't have that package installed.
3. Open xxx.xcworkspace instead of xxx.codeproj with Xcode and try to run from there.

Use a local version of the CLI like yarn react-native run-ios or npm run react-native run-ios. The npx command may still pick up the global version on some occasions